# how to calculate from date of birth in a single sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i want to find the age of employee with highest salary in the database.
i tried this query

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(SYSDATE(),'%Y-%m-%d'),
(SELECT birth_date FROM salaries as s, employees as e WHERE salary = (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM salaries) and s.emp_no = e.emp_no)/365.25);
```

but its not working.[this picture contain database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/To2ML.png)

Comment: this link contain the whole database https://github.com/datacharmer/test_db/archive/master.zip

Comment: Calculate the age first and then do where statement of Salary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original attempt seemed to have a number of minor problems, though the overall approach seems sound to me.  Just take the `DATEDIFF()` between the birth date of the employee with the maximum salary and the current datetime.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(SYSDATE(), e.birth_date) / 365.25
FROM salaries s
INNER JOIN employees e
    ON s.emp_no = e.emp_no
WHERE s.salary = (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM salaries)
```

Changes I made include using an explicit inner join between your tables and also computing the date difference in a different way.

Note that this query would return stats for multiple employees should more than one employee tie for the maximum salary.  In absence of further requirements, this seems like a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: Thank you for the help plz tell me the problems in my query

Comment: Your use of `DATE_FORMAT()` might not work (I didn't test it), and you have several layers of nested queries which are unnecessary.  One subquery to find the maximum salary is all you need.